# sssd only authenticates against first domain in domains list unless domain specified in login

Tags: linux, centos, kerberos, pam

I am currently moving from using pam_krb5 to pam_sss as pam_krb5 is no longer available at CentOS/RHEL 8

We currently use two AD domains each with unique user names. In the old pam configuration we had the following lines.

```
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so realm=DOM1.LOCAL try_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so realm=DOM2.LOCAL use_first_pass

account     sufficient    pam_krb5.so realm=DOM1.LOCAL
account     sufficient    pam_krb5.so realm=DOM2.LOCAL

password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so realm=DOM1.LOCAL try_first_pass banner=Windows
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so realm=DOM2.LOCAL use_first_pass banner=Windows

session     optional      pam_krb5.so realm=DOM1.LOCAL
session     optional      pam_krb5.so realm=DOM2.LOCAL
```

this allowed us to use passwords from our AD from either domain (account names all unique between domains) and this would login using a Unix account of the same name (stored in NIS)

I have tried to implement this in sssd by putting multiple domain configurations in the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

Like this

```
[sssd]
    services = nss, pam
    domains = DOM1.LOCAL,DOM2.LOCAL
    re_expression = (((?P<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?P<name>.+$))|((?P<name>[^@]+)@(?P<domain>.+$))|(^(?P<name>[^@\\]+)$)) 
    debug_level = 7

[domain/DOM1.LOCAL]
    id_provider = proxy
    proxy_lib_name = nis
    auth_provider = krb5

    krb5_server = dc1.dom1.local,dc2.dom1.local
    krb5_realm = DOM1.LOCAL
    krb5_ccachedir = /tmp
    krb5_ccname_template = FILE:%d/krb5cc_%U
    debug_level = 7

[domain/DOM2.LOCAL]
    id_provider = proxy
    proxy_lib_name = nis
    auth_provider = krb5

    krb5_server = dc1.dom2.local,dc2.dom2.local
    krb5_realm = DOM2.LOCAL
    krb5_ccachedir = /tmp
    krb5_ccname_template = FILE:%d/krb5cc_%U
    debug_level = 7

[nss]
    debug_level = 7

[pam]
    debug_level = 7
```

With the above setup I can ssh successfully to the server if I specify the username@domainname@linux_server

e.g.     ssh user1@dom1.local@myserver

But if I miss out the domainname then only the first domain in the 'sssd' domains list gets is looked up.

If user1 is in dom1.local and user2 is in dom2.local

```
ssh user1@linux_server     - Works 
ssh user2@linux_server     - Fails
```

If I switch the order of the domains in the domains parameter in sssd then

```
ssh user1@linux_server     - Fails
ssh user2@linux_server     - Works
```

The log files show that only one domain is being used dependent on which is first in the list.

Can someone give me some pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I've had the same issue, and found the answer completely by accident trying to figure out how I might re-add pam_krb.so.

What I know you'll need:

```
auth sufficient pam_sss.so domains=DOM1.LOCAL
auth sufficient pam_sss.so domains=DOM2.LOCAL
account sufficient pam_sss.so domains=DOM1.LOCAL
account sufficient pam_sss.so domains=DOM2.LOCAL
```

I don't know how to setup the `password` and `session` sections however, and I have a weird setup with single LDAP source with several Kerberos domains.

Src is from some SSSD bug notes here: https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/3668
Edit: added spaces for clarity, since I failed to proofread the preview.

Comment: And I know this has been here for 9 months. I just figured I can't be the only person who needs SSSD to search multiple domains without specifying user domain in login, since I haven't figured out an easy way to explain that to windows users that just want to ssh in to the system.